# Reproduction is limited by mutation

Tags: post-apocalypse, population, far-future, mutation, future

In the year 2020, a cosmic event caused large-scale mutation in humans. Every woman could reproduce only once in her lifetime.

Two hundred years later, what would be the population and composition of humans on earth? Will racial, geographical and any other distinctions affect the number of humans left?

Comment: Hello Niteesh, and welcome to the site.  SE's basic model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  Your question is much too broad as it expects us to analyze every possible ethnic distribution possible in a 200 year period.  This quesiton would be too broad if asked about any but the smallest individual nations.  It also requires us to address cultural (political, social, & religious) changes that may - or may not - change as a result of this mutation.  The truth is, the answer is anything you want or need for your story.

Comment: @JBH math and known fertility replacement rates gives good guidelines on the upper bounds of how many people would remain.

Comment: @RonJohn, if all the OP was asking for was the probable number of people on the planet, you'd be absolutely right.  But he's also asking about racial, geographical, "and any other" distinctions.  Are you prepared to explain how many people will be in each of the 200 some odd nations on the planet?  Or how many people of each race there will be (and hope there's no intermarriage...)?

Comment: I got what @JBH was trying to say. But what I was looking for was a general overview of the population. Would some areas be depopulated? WIll any one race be dominant?

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog Current places that are overpopulated or have very strict working conditions (India, China, Japan) are going to die out. They won't be able to support the aging population which will put a strain on the current generation, who will overwork to support their family/lifestyle rather than have kids and keep the population going. This would repeat a couple of times, until its too late and there isn't enough new people to keep the economy going.

Comment: @Shadowzee you can perhaps add this as an answer?

Comment: "*what I was looking for was a general overview of the population.*" That's an invitation for "Vote To Close -- Too Broad".

Comment: @RonJohn just the word 'general' does not make the question too broad.

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog I think its better as a comment, since it doesn't address your end question about the population left after 200 years. Its more of a consideration when doing the maths. If anything look at chinas 1 child policy and japans work culture which have left their population distributions in a very awkward situation.

Comment: If the question were worded to merely seek the general trends and key influences, that would be answerable here. But the question seems worded to seek an analysis which is too broad for this venue. Also, the vagaries of politics (and thereby policies) involved is unpredictable and a matter of opinion. Quite a bit of fiction has been written about rapidly-declining populations, much of it contradictory.

Comment: @RonJohn, I think you meant that last comment for Niteesh.  Niteesh, the Stack Exchange Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  The more specific your question, the less likely it'll be closed.  We're trying to help you understand how SE works.  When used as intended, you get high quality answers.

Comment: @JBH Thank you. But I did not intend to seek out what happens to each and every race or what happens in every geographical location. Blade Wraith 's answer is a very good example of the answer I was trying to find. I just wanted to know how people of different races or different regions interact with each other in such a scenario.

Comment: Niteesh, you may not have intended it, but it's what you asked for.  Have you read through our [help]? It's why you have 3 of 5 close votes.

Comment: If you had added the tag 'science-based' I would have find the premise hard to swallow 'a single mutation, globally and instantaneously applied' that would cause women to be able to reproduce only once. Er .. how? Single follicle produced? Ovaries enter total shutdown after giving birth? They die during labor? Other? Whatever you choose, be assured that this will have a profound effect on women in choosing a mate (if at all  - the die during labor option) and other behavior, and the mode of the mutation is rather more important than race or geographical distribution ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This started out as a comment and sort of snowballed from there

**Total Anarchy**

It takes two humans to make another, but once that has happened (in happy and loving relationship) then no more are produced by those two people, then take into account the some woman are unable to have babies means that the population will shrink exponentially.

I won't redo RonJohn's maths as its right. as is his statement that there wouldn't be many humans left.

**Racial Geographical etc**

This could change, people could see what was happening and let go of old prejudices... and all come together to pool resources and do their best to makes humans last as long as possible...

And maybe, just maybe if they do this, they'll get to see the rare flying pig before they die.

Its FAR more likely that humanity will fracture pointing fingers at one race or another as to the cause of the downfall of humanity

**Chaos would reign**

Humans are all dying out, putting strain on the remaining population to keep systems running and caring for the elderly which is now significantly more in number than those capable of caring for them, eventually there isn't enough police to stop thieves and looters from sacking the emptying homes and businesses, Countries economies collapse due to extreme worker shortages. the world loses its international trade networks and groups nearby to each other begin subsistence living... only producing enough to feed themselves. those that band together will likely continue to trade with others nearby but all of them know the end of humanity is coming in a few generations, sped up by those that don't want to move from their homes and happy memories, destined to die alone

**However... How could it be made to work?**

Potentially... the mutation that caused this made women unable to have more than one birth. but it makes twins or triplets much more likely. you would still have great pressures and probably civil unrest but humans might survive a bit longer.

*Or...*

The mutation stopped Woman from having more than one... but that same mutation somehow made it so it weakened the male sperm in men's, so many many more woman are produced, then a single man could have many children spread across many woman, obviously this would cause a few relationship and social issues as we stand at this point. as men would be **required** to reproduce with many women... for the survival of the species!!! *its a responsibility most men would be willing to make*

The numbers of humans worldwide would still decrease however but it could extend Humanities presence that little bit further. but if that were the case then there would be a huge population drop before the remaining governments forced the policy changes to allow men to do so. potentially even force them.

If this were the case it would also be a very strange situation to find humanity in, Lesbians would be quite common providing they had one child each then this would be permitted, however gay men would be severely frowned upon. an order of magnitude more than they are today (I'm meaning worldwide, i'm not having a go at the LBGT community!!!) and much much more so then they were 100 years ago

Comment: "gay men would be severely frowned upon" I'd like to remind everybody that gay men can (and do) father children. Indeed, they've been doing so since the dawn of humanity.

Comment: @AngelPray, i completely agree, however as they have also been frowned upon previously, it would give those people that do frown yet another reason to do so. i genuinely was not disrespecting the gay community but stating what is an unfortunate fact

Comment: A combination of fewer male children and an increase in twins and triplets (meaning women still produces enough children to sustain the population) would make most of the problems dissappear. There would still be a problem with sudden mass deaths -- if a large portion of the population just dies one day, it will take centuries to recover from it with no way to speed up the process (we can just have more kids as it is now and recover in a fairly short amount of time). This should make war less likely, as recovering from a war takes forever.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph about lesbians.

Comment: @Clearer "*There would still be a problem with sudden mass deaths*" like Indonesian tsunamis.

Comment: @RonJohn, Its just an odd thought i had about human psychology, in the situation i suggested where male offspring were less likely, then lesbians would be common place monogamous relationships very rare and gay relationships most likely frowned upon. its not so important for the answer as it is an interesting aside that may be a helpful idea for the story... Also... is Tsunamis right? not having a go, i just always thought it was like sheep, Tsunami being singular and plural based on the context of the sentence

Comment: @Clearer, indeed a combination would likely mean that the declined would be drastically slowed or possibly stopped, but as i was unsure of how the OP would want his world to work i didn't know if he wanted a gradual decline or for sustainable population

Comment: @BladeWraith the US Geological Survey thinks you add an "s" to make it plural: https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-tsunamis

Comment: @BladeWraith also, lesbianism is biological, and having women live together **out of necessity** (not enough men to go around) shouldn't be referred to as such.

Comment: @BladeWraith as far as gays being frowned upon... they just leave more women for the 95% of men who are heterosexual.

Comment: @RonJohn, Fair enough on the s, i wasn't sure, seem it doesn't have one in the UK... perhaps its just a region difference. also, I didn't mean lesbianism in terms of just living together. i was referring to romantic relationships. but if the ratio of men to women became as asymetric as i was suggesting then it could cause severe population issues which would lead to social issues for gay men.

Answer (score 3):

> In the year 2020, a cosmic event caused large-scale mutation in humans. Every woman could reproduce only once in her lifetime.
>
> Two hundred years later, what would be the composition of humans on earth?

Given that the replacement birth rate is about **2.3 children/woman**, there wouldn't be that many humans left after eight generations.  (7.7 **billion** people divided by 2.3 eight times leaves you with only 9.8 **million** people remaining.  Will they band together or die separately?)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-replacement_fertility

```
Taken globally, the total fertility rate at replacement was 2.33 children per woman in 2003.
```

> Racial, geographical and any other distinctions in consideration.

That would make as much difference as it does now.

Comment: Will they band together or die separately? That's worth exploring.

Comment: @Niteesh That's really up to you. It probably depends on how the news breaks and how dire the situation is.